# Yet another differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

*Hello,*

I would appreciate any help solving the following equation:

$$\begin{align}
y''[t] + \dfrac{d}{m}y'[t] + \dfrac{k}{m}y[t] = G \\
\end{align}$$
subject to:
$$t[0] = t0$$
$$t'[0] = 0$$

This is not HW, this is for a website where I try to simulate object attached to a spring falling, as I presented in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185897/help-solving-differential-equation/185913#185913) question; I just forgot to add damping (d) force so that the object will stop its movement after a while.

*Thank you!*

Comment: You can ask [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) for such questions

Comment: This is a [damped harmonic oscillator](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html) ([cont'd.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda2.html)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply through by $m$ to give $my'' + dy' + ky = Gm.$ First, find the complementary function by solving the homogeneous equation $my'' + dy' + ky = 0.$ Use the trial function $y(t) = e^{\lambda t}$. We get $(m\lambda^2 + d\lambda +k)e^{\lambda t} = 0.$ Since $e^{\lambda t} > 0$ we need to solve $m\lambda^2 + d\lambda +k = 0$ for $\lambda.$ Whence:

$\lambda_{\pm} = \frac{1}{2m}(-d \pm \sqrt{d^2 - 4mk}) \, .$

The complimentary function is then $y(t) = ae^{\lambda_-} + be^{\lambda_+}$ for any $a$ and $b$. Next, we need to find the particular integral. Since the right hand side of $my'' + dy' + ky = Gm$ is constant, we try $y(t) = \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a constant. Putting that into $my'' + dy' + ky = Gm$ gives $k\alpha = Gm$ and so $\alpha = Gm/k.$ The general solution is then:

$y(t) = ae^{\lambda_-} + be^{\lambda_+} + \frac{Gm}{k} \, .$

Finally, we impose the initial conditions that $y(0) = t_0$ and $y'(0) = 0.$ You will get two simultaneous equations in $a$ and $b$. Solve them gives:

$a = \frac{m\lambda_+(Gm-kt_0)}{k\sqrt{d^2-4mk}} \, , $

$b = \frac{m\lambda_-(Gm-kt_0)}{k(d^2-4mk)} \, . $

Provided I've not made a silly mistake, I get:

$y(t) = \frac{m}{k}\left[ G + \frac{(Gm-kt_0)}{\sqrt{d^2-4mk}}\left(\lambda_+e^{\lambda_-t} + \lambda_-e^{\lambda_+t}\right) \right] \, . $

Comment: And if $d^2-4mk\lt0$, you might find it more convenient to express the answer in terms of sines and cosines, instead of complex exponentials.

Comment: In reality the solution will be a product of a phase shifted cosine and a real exponential. But we need to know the numbers first.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I'll try it and I really got to take again that math course... thanks again :)